# How to pass the multiple values to the server using NSURLSESSION in Objective c

Tags: php, objective-c, iphone, ios9, xcode7

I want to pass the multiple values to my server like 1.phonenum,2.name 3.details 4.email.etc...

my server working on PHP. i want to pass the data to the based upon the key values of the fields.

phone number  U_pnum:123456789   Name   U_name:naveen  details   U_details:developer   email U_email:xyz@gmail.com .

i want to send the data using NSUrlSession.
i write some code ... but i am not getting the any response from my server .

please  help me .

thank You.

Comment: Please post your php code and objective c code.

Comment: why i using REST CLIENT in google chrome ..i am getting the response like     successfully updated the details.    like {response,Yes}

Comment: My point is how can we modify your code to send key values if you dont post how did you send the data and I think you have successfully send data to your server and your server has a reponse.

Comment: sorry @jameshwart lopez      i don't have PHP code.  the he(php developer) send me the only key values of that fields.       i am coping my objective c code  now check this one.                                                          
    NSURLSession *session=[NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSString *url=[NSString

Comment: I see.Just post some of your objective c code.

Comment: stringWithFormat:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577741/send-data-and-parameter-to-server"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    request.HTTPMethod=@"POST";

    
    
    NSDictionary *dictionary=@{@"mobile":@"reqnumber",@"password":@"000111",@"uid":@"78548YTGDRFERF542148524HJYT",@"sim_code":@"+91",@"operator_name":@"Idea"};
    NSError *error=nil;
    NSLog(@"%@",dictionary);
    NSData *datauplaod=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",datauplaod);

Comment: if (!error) {
        NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask=[session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:datauplaod completionHandler:^(NSData *dataupload,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error){
            
            NSLog(@"%@",uploadTask);
            
        }];
        [uploadTask resume];
        
    }
    
 write the code like that.

Comment: Please add the code to the Q and put it into code tags.

Comment: ok @Amin Negm-Award i am new to Stackoverflow .i will update my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];



     NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourServerUrl/postFile.php"];
        NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        NSString * params =@"U_pnum=valueofU_pnum&U_name=valueofU_name&U_details=valueofU_details&U_email=valueofU_email";
        [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                              NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
                                              if(error == nil)
                                              {
                                                  NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                  NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);
                                              }

                                          }];
        [dataTask resume];
```

Comment: I am getting the error like This                                                  2015-12-14 14:29:34.363 LCall[3718:1197217] Response:<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x14e693d50> { URL: http://45254.552/index.php/webservices/mobile_login } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Mon, 14 Dec 2015 08:59:37 GMT";
    Server = "Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.30";
} } (null)

Comment: 2015-12-14 14:29:34.364 LCall[3718:1197217] Data = {"response":"no","error":"This username or password mismatch"}

Comment: I can see that status code is 200 means means the request is successful

Comment: the response of the server you use is " {"response":"no","error":"This username and password mismatch"} " that means that the request you have sent is successful and you have sent the correct key.

Comment: Thank YOU                                                                                               That means i successfully Updated my Data.. Into  server.  :P     but ..... i am getting the "response no".how can i resolve this issues

Comment: Please make sure your data you send  to the server is correct.Its like a Login page that if you input the wrong username and password. The server (PHP) will response username and password is incorrect or mismatch

Comment: And please do accept my answer as correct by clicking the check icon.

Comment: k got it   thank you

Comment: Your welcome my fried. :D

Comment: hi now i am facing a new problem.           i want to send the dynamic data means i am saving the data in the string i want to send this information to the server.     check this code once                                                 
  '  NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *num=lable.text;        
    [defaults setObject:num forKey:@"Number"];
    [defaults synchronize];'        i want to send the data "num" as the value. .  means what the data hold by the num i,i want to send it to the server.   Thank you.

Comment: How to Pass the string value in to the another string.                                 here reqnum is the textfield                                                                 NSString *reqnumber=reqnum.text;                                                                NSString * num =@ "mobile=reqnumber";                      NSLog(@"%@",num);                                                                      output is:: mobile=reqnumber.                                But I want to pass the value which are enter by the user in the text filed. like mobile=123       Please Help Me ...

Comment: help me  friend   :)   @jameshwart lopez,@Amin Negm-Awad,@rckoenes

Comment: @NAVEEN Please create another question.

Comment: it will take 1 more day for asking another equation.. @jameshwart lopez

Comment: join here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/97927/naveen-kumar-and-jameshwart?tab=general lets chat.heheh

Comment: i  don't have 20 reputation points .. i can't chat @jameshwart lopez

Comment: you dont have a choice but ask another question. And its better.

Comment: ok Thank You.    You don't have any idea how to resolve this issues.